# What is the difference between #+NAME and #+LABEL in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

```
#+CAPTION: kernel version
#+LABEL: fig:myfigure
#+NAME: fig:myfigure
[[/home/victor/myblog/pic4.png]]
```

In org-mode, It seems that `#+LABEL` and `#+NAME` are both used for cross references. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure that #+LABEL is being deprecated in favor of #+NAME.